# How can I Use SMTP in Dockerized Django web app running on AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, email, smtp

I have a Django web app running in a Docker container which in due course will run live in an AWS EC2 instance (but for development is running on my Windows 10 laptop).

As the web app wants to send emails for various reasons, I would like to know the simplest approach for this, both for AWS operation, presumably using Amazon's Simple Email Service (SES), and for my development.

Having read that the Docker container needed to include an SMTP relay, I spent some time setting up the neat looking relay at https://hub.docker.com/r/turgon37/smtp-relay

But despite the claimed simplicity of the config setup, I had trouble with this (probably my fault, although the documentation was somewhat ambiguous in places as it was obviously written by someone whose native language is not English!). More to the point, it occurred to me that the claim an SMTP relay was needed in the container may have been nonsense, because surely one can just map container port 25 to the host's port 25 ?!

So in summary, has anyone had this requirement, i.e. for using SMTP in a Docker container, and what is the simplest approach?

TIA

Regards

John R